# Loading a custom skin onpage/window load by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, winamp

I want to load a custom .wsz skin on page-load on my website.
I still don't understand how to do it to make it work.
Here a snippet with my code:
https://codepen.io/cat999/pen/rNOOjJP

here my js

```
const webamp = new Webamp({
    initialTracks: [{
        metaData: {
            artist: "DJ Mike Llama",
            title: "Llama Whippin' Intro",
        },
        url: "https://cdn.rawgit.com/captbaritone/webamp/43434d82/mp3/llama-2.91.mp3",
        duration: 5.322286,
    }],
})

webamp.onMinimize(() => {
  const webampEl = document.getElementById('webamp')
  webampEl.style.display = 'none'
})

webamp.renderWhenReady(document.getElementById('app')).then(() => {
  document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    const webampEl = document.getElementById('webamp')
    webampEl.style.display = 'none'
  })

  document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const webampEl = document.getElementById('webamp')
    webampEl.style.display = 'block'
  })
})
```

Here below the skins I would like to see on my page-load

https://srv-file6.gofile.io/download/KwUySB/Aphex_Twin_-_Windowlicker.wsz

How I should improve my js code to make It work?